# Error When Writing Beginner Python 3 Celsius to Fahrenheit Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through the first chapter of my book and have already ran into an issue when writing out this example code:

```
# File: chaos.py 
# A simple program illustrating chaotic behavior. 

def main(): 
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x = eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")) 
    for i in range(10):
    x = 3.9 * x * (i - x)
    print(x)

main()
```

When I run this code in jGrasp, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

I don't know why this error is coming up and if someone could explain it to me that would be very helpful!

Comment: Your book uses `eval` in the first chapter? Then I hope that the chapter starts with "`eval` is dangerous. Never use it in real applications." If not, burn this book and scatter the ashes to the four winds.

Comment: @Matthias At the top of the code snippet: `# File: chaos.py`, `# A simple program illustrating chaotic behavior.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Python 2, but the code expects you to use Python 3. In Python 3 the function `input` will return a string whilst in Python 2 it'll evaluate the string you put in and return whatever it evaluated to.

Switch to Python 3 or use `raw_input` instead of `input`.